# What would cause a furnace to randomly fail to light roughly once a week?

Tags: hvac, furnace

Roughly once a week my furnace will shut off. No error codes are flashing. I turn the switch off and turn it back on and it will relight without an issue or error. There was a single occasion where it took two attempts to light. This leads me to believe that the furnace is shutting off when it fails to ignite multiple times. New filters are in and have already spent over 1000 having an hvac company come to address other issues (control board and limit switch). Any help would be really appreciated.

The furnace is roughly 13 years old - Goodman model number GMH950904CXAC

Comment: Sounds familiar, though fortunately for me it is generally a few weeks between failures. Make/model/age/size of furnace?

Comment: Added to the description - sorry for not including originally! Glad to know i'm not alone.

Answer (score 2):

There are two classes of problems here; you'll have to figure out which one you're facing.

### Flame proving failure

This means that the gas does ignite reliably but the furnace controls aren't able to confirm the fact. This is usually caused by a dirty flame sensing rod but also can be caused by flame not hopping from the first burner to the last burner quickly enough.

### Failure to ignite

This means there's never any flame at all. Likely causes are that the hot surface igniter doesn't get hot enough or the gas valve doesn't open. Both of these are much less likely to cause an intermittent problem like you've described -- usually when one of these components fails

The flame proving failure is more common/likely. Cleaning the flame sensor rod is an easy DIY task: remove the rod, scrub it with fine sandpaper or even a kitchen scouring pad, re-install. There's a YouTube video in which a technician demonstrates flame sensor removal from a Goodman furnace [over there](https://youtu.be/xex15Fp5HHA?t=237) (he's replacing the sensor).

You can watch the gas ignite a few times to be sure that the flame spreads across the burners properly. You should see the hot surface igniter glow a bright orange-yellow color, then hear a click of the gas valve and see and hear a near-instant "whoosh!" of flame spread across all the burners. If you see visible delay or pause in the flame advancing across the burners that could also cause your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is your water heater on the same gas pipe as the furnace?

It's possible that your gas pressure at the furnace is marginal due to inadequate pipe size or excessive distance, and if the water heater happens to be already running at the moment that your furnace wants to start, you may not have enough pressure to light the furnace promptly enough to satisfy the flame detector within the allowed time limit.

[This PDF](https://igate.northernplumbing.com/manuals/goodman/gmh95.pdf) for your furnace shows the method of checking gas pressure (page 35) and adjusting the regulator if necessary. They want all gas appliances to be running when you check pressure.

You are not seeing any fault codes but the controller may be faulting out and storing codes. You can review the last 5 fault codes using the procedure on page 39.